# Pyinstaller Error when converting .py to .exe

Tags: python, typeerror, pyinstaller

Whenever I try to put any .py file into pyinstaller I always get an error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` I havent been able to find any fixes that make sense.

Ive tried reinstalling pyinstaller and different files.

I dont think there is any code problems since this occurs no matter what file I use

Expected: a compiled exe file.

Actual Result:
`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` 
error and nothing is compiled

Comment: Just a suggestion, try with a simple python file first. If that is converted then some problem in your code else pyinstaller setup has some problem.

Comment: Please show an example of a command you've tried

Answer (score 1):

First, uninstall pyinstaller completely with `pip uninstall pyinstaller` then delete `C:/Users/<Username>/AppData/Roaming/Pyinstaller` directory.

Next Install pyinstaller with `pip install -U pyinstaller`.

If still shows the same error try to replace `bindepend.py` from [here](https://github.com/Loran425/pyinstaller/blob/14b6e65642e4b07a4358bab278019a48dedf7460/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py) in `<Python path>\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend` directory.